# strtok() not working as expected

Tags: c, strtok

I'm splitting file buffer on newline delimiter using `strtok()` function, but the result I'm getting is not what I expected.

```
patient->fullName = strtok(fileContent, "\n");
patient->dateOfBirth = strtok(NULL, "\n");
patient->height = strtok(NULL, "\n");
patient->waistMeasurement = strtok(NULL, "\n");
patient->weight = strtok(NULL, "\n");
patient->comment = strtok(NULL, "\n");
```

When I save delimited values into struct members every member displays fine later on except the first one, `fullName`. If I got it right it displays address value instead. Here is the output:

[image]

Since I'm still not familiar with C, could you please tell me how can I get full name that's actually written in the file in the place of this pointer address?

**EDIT:**

Creation of `fileContent`:

```
FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "r");

fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
long size = ftell(file);
rewind(file);

char *fileContent = malloc(size + 1);
fread(fileContent, size, 1, file);
```

Patient:

```
struct Patient
{
    char *fullName;
    char *dateOfBirth;
    char *height;
    char *waistMeasurement;
    char *weight;
    char *comment;
};

struct Patient *patient = malloc(sizeof(*patient));

patient->fullName = malloc(sizeof(NAME_LENGTH));
patient->dateOfBirth = malloc(sizeof(BIRTHDAY_LENGTH));
patient->height = malloc(sizeof(HEIGHT_LENGTH));
patient->waistMeasurement = malloc(sizeof(WAIST_LENGTH));
patient->weight = malloc(sizeof(WEIGHT_LENGTH));
patient->comment = malloc(sizeof(COMMENT_LENGTH));
```

File content saved in file (it's encrypted though):

```
Qevms Wqspgmg
49.46.5336.
534,9
84,7
28,6
Li'w jygomrk eaiwsqi hyhi!
```

Comment: It would be sensible to show the value stored in `fileContent` before you butchered it with `strtok()`.  It would also be sensible to show the definition of the structure which `patient` points to.  Those are basic requirements to make this somewhere near an MCVE ([MCVE]) — though you'd still arguably be a bit on the over-minimal side.

Comment: Note that the space allocated by the `malloc()` calls is all lost by your use of `strtok()` — you are leaking.  You need to use `strcpy()` to copy strings into the allocated space.  You need to check that you allocated enough space before you copy.  Or you should use `strdup()` — `patient->fullName = strdup(strtok(fileContent, "\n"));`.  Also, because you're copying pointers to `fileContent`, if you read the next line into `fileContent`, it will change the values of the strings pointed at by the previous `patient` record.  Or `fileContent` goes out of scope and is used for another purpose.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you very much. This worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the space allocated by the `malloc()` calls is all lost by your use of `strtok()` — you are leaking.  You need to use `strcpy()` to copy strings into the allocated space.  You need to check that you allocated enough space before you copy.  Or you could use the POSIX function [`strdup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html) — `patient->fullName = strdup(strtok(fileContent, "\n"));`.  (That's a tad risky; I'd usually check the return from `strtok()` before passing it to `strdup()` — but it makes the point.)

Also, because you're copying pointers to `fileContent`, if you read the next line into `fileContent`, it will change the values of the strings pointed at by the previous `patient` record.  Or, when `fileContent` goes out of scope and is used for another purpose, the data will change again.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm using fileContent just inside the scope of this function to read from text file and save values to structure, but duplicating string values into allocated space did the thing.